# which version of linux should I use?

Tags: linux

I have an old computer that I want to install Linux on it and use it as file server (for backup). My old computer has 512MB ran and an old Pentium. Which Linux should I use?

Comment: try over at http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

Since your building a file server, you may want to look at a distro like [OpenFiler](http://www.openfiler.com/).

Answer (score 0):

I use Debian on just such a rig. I used the text mode installer and didn't install X. It works quite nicely. I used the netinstall and started out with a pretty minimal system, which is all you'll need for a file server.